# How to add fontawsome inside button in jquery on first click

Tags: jquery

```
$(".MobileNames").click(function () {
    $(this).append($('<i class="fa fa fa-check"></i>'))
    LoadMobieByName($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

When user clicks the button the first time, I want to add the Font Awesome icon to it; but not on subsequent clicks. How do I do that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) This is a very straight-forward thing to do with jQuery. Where *specifically* are you stuck? Have you had a good look at [the jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com)?

Comment: When you were asking your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful information in it. There was also an entire toolbar of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help. *And* a preview area located between the text area and the Post Your Question button (so that you'd have to scroll past it to find the button, to encourage you to look at it) showing what your post would look like when posted. Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the [jQuery find() method](https://api.jquery.com/find/) 
Like this :

```
$(".MobileNames").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.find("i.fa-check").length < 1)
        $this.append($('<i class="fa fa fa-check"></i>'))
    LoadMobieByName($this.attr("id"));
});
```

```js
$(".MobileNames").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.find("i.fa-check").length < 1)
        $this.append($('<i class="fa fa fa-check"></i>'))
    //LoadMobieByName($this.attr("id"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button class="MobileNames">
Test
</button>
```

Comment: Ideally without unnecessarily repeatedly calling `$()`. Instead, `var $this = $(this);` and then use `$this`.